# Bootstrap stacked cards

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a flexbox column with three bootstrap 4 cards. when I resize the container the first one get taller or shorter because of its responsive design. What I want is to keep the whole container height constant and shrink and grow the middle card. Here is my code:
HTML

```
<div >
        <div class="cards">

            <div class="card">
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                   1234
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                   5678
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div><!-- /card-one -->

        <div class="card">
               <p>content for card two</p>
        </div><!-- /card-two -->

        <div class="card">
              <p>content for card three</p>
        </div><!-- /card-three -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cards {
display: flex;
flex-flow: column;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Fiddle:
[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/93u2k75h/36/)

Thanks

Comment: You have two `col-md-6` columns in your first card, which get stacked on tablet and above. You also have only a tiny bit of content in the second card -- there's nothing to make it grow. Are you asking how you can make the three cards take up 100% of the height of their container, while only keeping the top and bottom cards constrained to the height of their content?

Comment: I think yes. What I want is to keep the whole container as of a constant height. And if top card grows to have the middle one shrinking.

Comment: I have modified my example.